# Define host and different request addr on curl

Tags: php, scripting, curl, nginx

I want to automatize the installation of some software on a new host for domains whose DNS servers don't direct this domain to the desired server.

Is it possible to go through the installation process using cURL? I'd need to set the REQUEST_HOST and REQUEST_ADDR to 2 different things then.

**Example:**

- I'd like to setup a wordpress blog gowordpress.tld on machine
  123.456.789.1
- The DNS record for gowordpress.tld is set to 987.654.321.1
- The webserver on Host 123.456.789.1 is set to servername
  .gowordpress.com (nginx)
- I'd like to go through the steps using a PHP script on Host
  123.456.789.1
- I'd like to use cURL.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to provide IP address in URI form and specify host as one of cURL option, with `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://123.123.123.123/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: gowordpress.tld') );
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

Or directly from command line you can do:

```
curl -H 'Host: gowordpress.tld' http://123.456.789.1/
```

To check only the response status and headers use the `-I` switch:

```
curl -I -H 'Host: gowordpress.tld' http://123.456.789.1/
```

Curl utility is available in all debian based systems: `apt-get install curl`

Comment: Should work, thanks. Point is I needed to automatize the installation of several Wordpress installations, so I needed the PHP part.